# How to add href link in bootbox dialog message

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Here is my jQuery code to the bootbox dialog box.

```
bootbox.dialog({ 
message: 'Message has been generated.<br><a href=<?php echo $site_url;?>/force_download.php?file_name=../folder_path/'+msg_split[1]+'.pdf>Click Here to download label</a> <br><b>Currently generated Lable is -&nbsp;<font color=red>'+msg_split[1]+'</font></b>',
title: 'Response',
buttons: {
warning: {
      label: "Ok",
      className: "btn-success",
         callback: function() {
         flushWarehouseInformation();
      }
    }
 }  
});
```

But for me href link is not working properly. 
How can I achieve this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you have included in your question is not enough to reproduce the error you're facing. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: `href` values should be set within quotes.

Comment: Here is the href link code in script.message: 'Message has been generated.<br><a href=<?php echo $site_url;?>/force_download.php?file_name=../folder_path/'+msg_split[1]+'.pdf>Click Here to download label</a> <br><b>Currently generated Lable is -&nbsp;<font color=red>'+msg_split[1]+'</font></b>',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
<a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>/force_download.php?file_name=../folder_path/'+msg_split[1]+'.pdf">Click Here to download label</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly wrap your URL in the quotes. Note the start and end of single quotes and double quotes.

```
message: 'Message has been generated.<br><a href="' + <?php echo $site_url;?> + '/force_download.php?file_name=../folder_path/' + msg_split[1] + '.pdf">Click Here to download label</a><br /><b>Currently generated Lable is -&nbsp;<font color="red">' + msg_split[1] + '</font></b>',
```